# I have message that $ is missing in line of this code

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

```
\begin{equation}

\begin{aligned}
\f(\kappa,\rho,\alpha,\beta_i,X_i;x_i,y_i) & =\dfrac{\exp \big(k cos(x_i-X_i)\big)}{2\pi I_0}\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{2\pi\big[1+\rho^2-2\rho \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2 I_0(\lambda \rho)}\exp \big(k \cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\dfrac{1}{\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)} \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2I_0(\lambda \rho)}\exp \big(k \cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}\cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]^{-1}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2I_0(\lambda \rho)} \exp \big(\cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}{\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i) \cos\alpha+\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i \sin\alpha)}\big]^{-1} 
\end{aligned}

\end{equation}
```

Where should I put the `$`?

Comment: remove the blank lines, you are not allowed paragraph breaks in math

Comment: unrelated but use `\bigl(...\bigr)`  never use `\big` which is the internal command used to define `\bigl` and `\bigr`

Comment: what mean by blank line@D

Comment: The blank line is an empty line, with only spaces.

Comment: @DoāaY.El-borai: The empty line between `\begin{aligned}` and `\f`: you should remove it, as well as the empty line before `\end{equation}`.

Comment: please explian how exactly i remove the empty line but appear error @G

Comment: @DoāaY.El-borai Remove also the blank line before `\end{equation}`.

Comment: @DoāaY.El-borai: Fine.  Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: IDO ALSO but error is stay   this massege appear( undefined control sequence)@e

Comment: @DoāaY.El-borai: This is a *different* error.  Are you sure that you really want `\f` and not, rather, `f`?

Comment: @DoāaY.El-borai Please see my answer

Comment: i show answer but i need f in my document ... when i write \f and remove blank line massege appear( undefined control sequence).. but i attempt write f without \ the file compile

Comment: I updated my answer @DoāaY.El-borai, so please accept if it is alright now ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined the macro `\f`; in the code below, I've set `\f` equal to just `f`.

Since the term `\frac{\exp\big(k\cos(x_i-X_i)\big)}{(2\pi)^2 I_0}` occurs repeatedly, I'd like to suggest that you give it a new, compact name, say `\zeta_i`.

The following may then be what you're looking for; note the extra linebreak in the final row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\f{f} % ??
\begin{document}
Put $\zeta_i= \dfrac{\exp \bigl(k\cos(x_i-X_i)\bigr)}{(2\pi)^2 I_0}$. 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\f(\kappa,\rho,\alpha,\beta_i,X_i;x_i,y_i) 
 &= \zeta_i\,\frac{(1-\rho^2)}{\bigl[1+\rho^2-2\rho \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\bigr]}\\
 &= \frac{\zeta_i}{\lambda\rho}\,\frac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}
    \frac{1}{\bigl[1-\frac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)} \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\bigr]}\\
 &= \frac{\zeta_i}{\lambda\rho}\,\frac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}  
    \bigl[1-\frac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}\cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\bigr]^{-1}\\
 &= \frac{\zeta_i}{\lambda\rho}\,\frac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)} 
    \bigl[1-\frac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i) \cos\alpha\\
 &\qquad\qquad +\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i \sin\alpha)\bigr]^{-1} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed your code a bit, to something that could compile:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(\kappa,\rho,\alpha,\beta_i,X_i;x_i,y_i) & =\dfrac{\exp \big(k cos(x_i-X_i)\big)}{2\pi I_0}\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{2\pi\big[1+\rho^2-2\rho \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2 I_0(\lambda \rho)}\exp \big(k \cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\dfrac{1}{\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)} \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2I_0(\lambda \rho)}\exp \big(k \cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}\cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]^{-1}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2I_0(\lambda \rho)} \exp \big(\cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}{\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i) \cos\alpha+\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i \sin\alpha)}\big]^{-1} \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

I have removed the blank lines you had inside the `aligned` environment, and the `\f`

If you really want blank lines, you need to mark them with percentage signs:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
%    
f(\kappa,\rho,\alpha,\beta_i,X_i;x_i,y_i) & =\dfrac{\exp \big(k cos(x_i-X_i)\big)}{2\pi I_0}\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{2\pi\big[1+\rho^2-2\rho \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2 I_0(\lambda \rho)}\exp \big(k \cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\dfrac{1}{\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)} \cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2I_0(\lambda \rho)}\exp \big(k \cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}\cos(y_i-\alpha-\beta_i X_i)\big]^{-1}\\
 & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^2I_0(\lambda \rho)} \exp \big(\cos(x_i-X_i)\big)\dfrac{(1-\rho^2)}{(1+\rho^2)}\big[1-\dfrac{2\rho}{(1+\rho^2)}{\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i) \cos\alpha+\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i \sin\alpha)}\big]^{-1}     
%
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

## Edit:

I originally compiled the code above in the `memoir` class, but the math was too wide, which is why i changed to `standalone`. In the `standalone` class I do get an error, but this error is not present in memoir, and the document still compiles to the shown picture

Comment: i solve it by  write f without \.... thanx alot

Comment: If this worked @DoāaY.El-borai then please press the tick mark under the arrows, so the question is closed :-)

Comment: `cos` and `sin` are not variable, so you should write `\cos` and `\sin` ...